# Is there any way to Integrate WordPress with Imgur for Image Hosting

Tags: images, api, uploads

I wanted to use Imgur for hosting all my WordPress website images. Till now I know how to integrate Imgur with a simple form using an [upload script](http://pastebin.com/vYRsGt4m). The process is well explained at [Subin's](http://subinsb.com/uploading-images-using-imgur-api-in-php)
Now what I want is to use the same Imgur API to automatically host every uploaded image to Imgur instead of wp-content folder. Is there any way for this? I didn't find any plugin for this yet.

P.S. [Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/)

Comment: It's possible, but I would not recommend it. You could use their API and bring up a media library of all your imgur uploads, select the image and have it put a short code into your page that would be read as an image. This however would require a fair amount of work and would have the same fall backs as any API heavy system. API's can change, do change and do get turned off. Along with the other big problem with API's, they aren't made for heavy use. Imgur only allows 12,500 requests per day. Which could be problematic depending on your site.

Comment: You're right about API's here, but as I am building a prototype which would be in closed beta, I really don't want to go ahead and invest into image hosting. Sure, later I will consider switching to AWS S3 or something similar but for now I think this would be good.

Comment: maybe the start of an anwser https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-imgur/